# Angular2 ag-grid datasource

Tags: typescript, angular, ag-grid

I am trying to get a ag-grid datasource to work in angular2, although I got the feeling that I am nearly there I am not able to fix the following issue with my current knowledge of angular/typescript.

The problem is that I have a function called returnRows, which works perfectly fine (see testdata variable). But the moment I try to call it within datasource.getRows I get the following exception: TypeError: this.returnRows is not a function in [gridOptions in PagetestComponent@2:2]. In the end I would like to replace the function with a service that gets the data from an api.

Here is my component.ts code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

import {AgGridNg2} from 'ag-grid-ng2/main';
import {GridOptions} from 'ag-grid/main';

import {PagetestService} from '..//services/pagetest.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample',
  templateUrl:'/static/app/pagetest/components/pagetest.component.html',
  directives: [AgGridNg2],
  providers: [PagetestService]
})

export class PagetestComponent implements OnInit{
    public gridOptions: GridOptions;
    private columnDefs: any[];
    private testdata: any[];

    constructor(
        public _routeParams: RouteParams,
        public _variantsService: PagetestService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.columnDefs = [
          {headerName: "ID", field: "_id",},
          {headerName: "CHR", field: "chr"},
          {headerName: "POS", field: "pos"},
          {headerName: "REF", field: "ref"},
          {headerName: "ALT", field: "alt"},
        ];
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
        this.gridOptions.datasource = this.dataSource;
        this.testdata = this.returnRows();
    }

    dataSource = {
        //rowCount : -1,
        pageSize: 1,
        overflowSize: 100,

        getRows: function(params: any){
            console.log(params)
            //var rowData = [
                //{"chr": "1", "_id": "1-22848972-A-C", "ref": "A", "pos": 22848972, "alt": "C"},
                //{"chr": "1", "_id": "1-33133968-T-C", "ref": "T", "pos": 33133968, "alt": "C"}
            //]
            rowData = this.returnRows();
            var rowsThisPage = rowData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
            console.log(rowsThisPage)
            var lastRow = -1;
            params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        }
    }

    returnRows(){
        var rowData = [
            {"chr": "1", "_id": "1-22848972-A-C", "ref": "A", "pos": 22848972, "alt": "C"},
            {"chr": "1", "_id": "1-33133968-T-C", "ref": "T", "pos": 33133968, "alt": "C"}
        ]
        return rowData
    }
}
```

Update, thanks @Dinistro for answering my initial question.

Updated code (partial):

```
getRows: (params: any) => {
    var rowData = this.returnRows();
    var rowsThisPage = rowData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
    var lastRow = -1;
    //if (rowData.length <= params.endRow) {
        //lastRow = rowData.length;
    //}
    // call the success callback
    params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
}
```

And added service to returnRows function.

```
returnRows() {
    var rowData: any;
    this._variantsService.getVariants().subscribe(
        variants => rowData = variants
    );
    console.log(rowData)
    return rowData;
}
```

This how ever results now in the error: TypeError: rowData is undefined in [gridOptions in PagetestComponent@2:2]. Probably a similar mistake but I can't get it to work.

pagetest.component.html

```
<h1>Pagetest</h1>
<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 350px;" class="ag-fresh"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  [columnDefs]="columnDefs"

  rowModelType = "pagination"

  enableColResize>
</ag-grid-ng2>
```

pagetest.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PagetestService {
  constructor (private http: Http) {}

  private _variantsUrl = '/api/variant/';  // URL to web api

  getVariants () {
    return this.http.get(this._variantsUrl)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
  private handleError (error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }

}
```

Comment: Some response would be great ;)

Comment: Do you use `rowData` somewhere in your HTML? Can you also add the HTML-template or create a plunker?

Comment: I will add my html template and my service as well , I can't get ag-grid-ng2 to work on plunker, sorry. I do not use rowData somewhere else. It only gives an error if I use the service to get the data instead of returning the hardcoded array. Maybe it does have something to do with asynchronous behaviour of the service?

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: It works great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use an [arrow-function](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/arrow-functions.html):

```
getRows: (params: any) => {
    console.log(params)
    //var rowData = [
    //{"chr": "1", "_id": "1-22848972-A-C", "ref": "A", "pos": 22848972, "alt": "C"},
    //{"chr": "1", "_id": "1-33133968-T-C", "ref": "T", "pos": 33133968, "alt": "C"}
    //]
    rowData = this.returnRows();
    var rowsThisPage = rowData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
    console.log(rowsThisPage)
    var lastRow = -1;
    params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
}
```

This will make sure, that the "this-context" is not changed

---

**For the updated question**

I see your error: You need to return the Observable, because otherwise, the `rowData` will not be loaded:

```
returnRows() {
    return this._variantsService.getVariants();
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
getRows: (params: any) => {
    this.returnRows().subscribe(rowData => {
        var rowsThisPage = rowData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);
        var lastRow = -1;
        //if (rowData.length <= params.endRow) {
        //lastRow = rowData.length;
        //}
        // call the success callback
        params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
    });
}
```

Comment: @RobertErnst An updated question or a vote would be great

Comment: Thanks for answering, this indeed fixes the problem. However (maybe you saw this coming already) I want to use a service to get data from an api. This gives me a similar error, probably a similar thing, I have edited my initial post.

Comment: @RobertErnst Can you add your attempt to extract the service. Or you can ask a new question, this would be a cleaner way.

Comment: I have added the updated returnRows function to use the service.