# how to do pagination in ag-grid for angular 2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

i am developing a grid with pagination component in angular 2 using ag-grid already tried the following code in the html.

```
[gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                 [showToolPanel]="showToolPanel"
                 [rowData]="rowData"

                 enableColResize
                 debug
                 rowHeight="30"
                 rowSelection="multiple"
                 rowModelType="pagination"
                 paginationPageSize = "15"
```

this result a grid with pagination buttons but the rowData is not loading but column headings are coming.I am loading the rowData and columnDefs from a service is that the reason why its not working ? am i doing it in the correct way ? any help is much appreciated

Comment: This answer helped me to get the pagination work
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934207/angular2-ag-grid-datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a datasource for pagination - take a look at the [Pagination Documenation][1] for more information, but in a nutshell:

```
var dataSource = {
        rowCount: 100, // for example
        getRows: function (params) { 
                var rowsThisPage = someService.getData(params.startRow, params.endRow);
                params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        };
}

gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
```

**Update**

Please take a look at the first [Pagination Example][2] - this illustrates how to do exactly what you're after.

I've modified the example slightly to fit into the code snippet below - this shows you how to load a file and set the datasource all in one block (although it would be better to separate these into separate methods):

```
// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
var allOfTheData = [];
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

    // do http request to get our sample data - not using any framework to keep the example self contained.
    // you will probably use a framework like JQuery, Angular or something else to do your HTTP calls.
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open('GET', '../olympicWinners.json');  // your static json file would go here
    httpRequest.send();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
            allOfTheData = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

            var dataSource = {
                rowCount: 20,
                getRows: function (params) {
                    // take a chunk of the array, matching the start and finish times
                    var rowsThisPage = allOfTheData.slice(params.startRow, params.endRow);

                    // see if we have come to the last page. if we have, set lastRow to
                    // the very last row of the last page. if you are getting data from
                    // a server, lastRow could be returned separately if the lastRow
                    // is not in the current page.
                    var lastRow = -1;
                    if (allOfTheData.length <= params.endRow) {
                        lastRow = allOfTheData.length;
                    }
                    params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
                }
            };

            gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: when i m trying with gridOptions.api.setDatasource(dataSource);  it throwing error because gridOptions is empty it doesn't have 'api' inside.

it happening because in the constructor  i have this code (same i got from the angular 2 example)

// we pass an empty gridOptions in, so we can grab the api out
        this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};

Comment: the api will be available for you to use once the gridReady event has been called - listen for that event and when called you can set the datasource

Comment: thank you so much genius :)  is there any documentation available for angular 2

Comment: Thank you! Documentation can be found https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/, but there is additional ng2 documentation under filtering, rendering and editing. If you're happy with this answer please mark it as accepted :-)